# Svelte Firebase: Unresolved function or method firestore()

Tags: javascript, firebase, svelte

I'm working with svelte on a todo list with firebase. I think I have everything installed, but I get the error in my firebase.js file: `Unresolved function or method firestore()` same for auth().
what is the reason for this?
My Code:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

var firebaseConfig = {
// my config here

};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is that a SvelteKit project? if so, is that code in the __layout.svelte file?

Comment: nope, I created it with npx degit sveltejs/template

Comment: so is that code in the main.js file? what's the version of firebase you are using?

Comment: Which Firebase version are you using ?

Comment: It is in the firbase.js file. im using the latest version i think.

Comment: I think you are using v8, and they recently released v9 this is a guide on how to upgrade https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the latest and recommended firebase version (9) your firebase.js looks like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { firebaseConfig } from "../firebase.config.js";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth();
export const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider(); 
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

and you have to include firebase in your package.json like:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "...",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/..."
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^1.0.0-next.30",
    "svelte": "^3.44.0",
    "vite": "^2.6.12",
    "firebase": "^9.1.3",
  }
}
```

This works fine for me.